# Reserved url is not being reserved

Tags: google-app-engine, url-routing

When I run my app, either via dev_appserver (local) or appcfy (live) it tells me

> WARNING  2016-04-04 10:22:23,538 appinfo.py:1113]
> The URL path "/form" is reserved and will not be matched.

app.yaml:

```
application: my-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /bower_components
  static_dir: bower_components

- url: /src/js
  static_dir: src/js

- url: /src/css
  static_dir: src/css

- url: /form
  script: main.application
  login: admin

- url: .*
  script: main.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

builtins:
- remote_api: on
- deferred: on
```

So that warning appears to be valid. However, navigating to `http://my-app.appspot.com/form` works just fine.

It saying *"The URL path "/form" is reserved and will not be matched."* and a google groups conversation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/ZmcU9nHLTI8) and even a SO question [why is GAE not detecting my form page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649612/why-is-gae-not-detecting-my-form-page) make you believe that the url path won't even reach your app router and show a 404 instead.

That is not the case though. I know for sure that the separate `/form` is being matched because it's the only route I have admin login enabled for, and that is working as expected.

---

The [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5983) referred to in that conversation mentions an update to the documentation (d.d. december 2014) to better reflect this situation. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?csw=1#Python_app_yaml_Reserved_URLs) only says this though:

> **Reserved URLs**
>
> All URLs that begin with `/_ah/` are reserved by App Engine for features or administrative purposes. Some URLs are routed to App Engine feature handlers, while others are called by App Engine for special purposes and are expected to be mapped to request handlers in your app (for example, `/_ah/warmup` for Warm-up Requests).

No mention of `/form` anywhere.

---

I don't want to change the url to something else just to avoid a warning that may be outdated, but I'm not sure if it is, or if something else is happening.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/release-notes) for 1.9.33 say:

> February 17, 2016 - Version 1.9.33
>
> App Engine notes
>
> The URL path "/form" is now allowed and will be forwarded to
> applications. Previously, this path was blocked.

So it looks like the warning is out of date.